# Difference between "sleeping with Sean Parker" and "sleeping on Sean Parker"?

Tags: differences, idioms, prepositions

In the movie Social Network, there is a scene where Sean Parker corrected a sentence said by a girl who he just spent a night with:

She was rather astonished when she realized the man standing in front of her was Sean Parker so she wanted to double confirm, "I just slept with Sean Parker?" Instead of replying her with a yes or a nod, Sean Parker said, "You just slept **on** Sean Parker." And he laid stress on the word "on".

> Sean Parker: I founded Napster.
>
> Amy: Sean Parker founded Napster.
>
> Sean Parker: Nice to meet you.
>
> Amy: [Surprised] You're Sean Parker?
>
> Sean Parker: Ah ha! You see, the shoe is on the other...
>
> Amy: Foot?
>
> Sean Parker: Table. Which has turned.
>
> Amy: I just slept with Sean Parker?
>
> Sean Parker: You just slept **on** Sean Parker.

Is there a different between "slept with Sean Parker" and "slept on Sean Parker"? What is the significance of emphasizing on the preposition "on"?

Comment: One is having sex, the other is using him as a mattress

Comment: The clip you posted is the one before the one with the dialog - and now in Spanish?

Comment: @mplungjan Not in spanish but I couldn't find the clip with that dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sleep on* is a play of words here.

You didn't know Sean Parker when you saw him -- you must have been sleeping all this while (you were unaware of developments related to Sean Parker).

Comment: Such literary play of words is outside grammar, usage and idiom, perhaps outside the scope of ELU, I don't know. :) As for the verb + *with*, well, you know.

Comment: I think a simpler interpretation is better. To *sleep on* something is to stop thinking about a question, so that one can approach it fresh in the morning— or literally to sleep on top of something. The latter is almost certainly the intended sense here— Amy says she *slept with* Sean as a euphemism for sex, but to Sean the sex was forgettable; her actually sleeping on top of him is what he remembers from the night before.

Comment: @choster Does that make Sean Parker an assh*le?

Comment: @user53578878979080099421313131 Sean Parker (the character as portrayed in the film) being something an assh*le is recurrent in the film.

Comment: @choster Oh no wonder!

Answer (score 2):

Slept **with** implies sex. Slept **on** implies sleeping next to, or physically on top of.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sleep+on+it

Comment: @Kris: *it* and *him* are importantly different.

Comment: @TimLymington Oh sure! Which is the reason I said 'play on words' not 'an idiom' in my answer.

Comment: But I thought they had sex?